# Dynamic NAV 2018 Web Service: Creating Sales Order Lines gets error "Standard Code Text does not exist...."

Tags: soap

In Dynamic NAV 2018, I exposed page Sales Order (id 36) as web service, I'm following some guides to create Sales Order Header and Sales Order Lines, the Header can be created successfully, but the Sales Lines always get error "Standard Code Text does not exist..."

```
SOWS.Sales_Order_VS_Service testcreateSO = new SOWS.Sales_Order_VS_Service();
testcreateSO.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

SOWS.Sales_Order_VS SOEntity = new SOWS.Sales_Order_VS();
testcreateSO.Create(ref SOEntity);
SOEntity.Sell_to_Customer_No = "44094";
SOEntity.Store_No = "S9003";
SOEntity.Location_Code = "S9003";

testcreateSO.Update(ref SOEntity);


SOEntity.SalesLines = new SOWS.Sales_Order_Line[1];
SOEntity.SalesLines[0] = new SOWS.Sales_Order_Line();
testcreateSO.Update(ref SOEntity);

SOEntity.SalesLines[0].Type = SOWS.Type.Item;
SOEntity.SalesLines[0].TypeSpecified = true;
SOEntity.SalesLines[0].No = "208122";
SOEntity.SalesLines[0].Quantity = 1;

testcreateSO.Update(ref SOEntity);



System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: 'The Standard Text does not exist. Identification fields and values: Code='208122''
```

Checking in table Sales Lines, a record of new order has been created but Type = 0 (means blank)

Document No_ Line No_ Sell-to Customer No_ Type No_ Location Code Document Type
SO210600017 10000 0 1

Please help

**Solution**

Instead of using only singe page Sales Order as web service, can expose page Sales Order Line as another web service, so full code as below:

```
SOWS.Sales_Order_VS_Service testcreateSO = new SOWS.Sales_Order_VS_Service();
testcreateSO.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

SOWS.Sales_Order_VS SOEntity = new SOWS.Sales_Order_VS();
testcreateSO.Create(ref SOEntity);
SOEntity.Sell_to_Customer_No = "44094";
SOEntity.Store_No = "S9003";
SOEntity.Location_Code = "S9003";

testcreateSO.Update(ref SOEntity);


//Using Sales Order Line page as web service from here

SOLinesWS.salesDocumentLines_Service saleslinesSV = new SOLinesWS.salesDocumentLines_Service
            {
                UseDefaultCredentials = true
            };

            SOLinesWS.salesDocumentLines saleslines = new SOLinesWS.salesDocumentLines();
            

            saleslines.documentType = SOLinesWS.documentType.Order;
            saleslines.documentTypeSpecified = true;
            saleslines.documentNumber = SOEntity.No;
            saleslines.type = SOLinesWS.type.Item;
            saleslines.typeSpecified = true;
            saleslines.number = "208122";
            saleslines.quantity = 1;
            saleslines.quantitySpecified = true;

saleslinesSV.Create(ref saleslines);
```